# How to get more frames from backtrace in tracemalloc snapshot comparisons (python 3.6)?

Tags: memory-leaks, python-3.6

### Description of my question

I'm trying to chase down a memory leak in a python 3.6 program.

For that I'm testing tracemalloc, which allows me to compare memory snapshots and print out a "backtrace".

The max number of frames in the backtrace should be set as the first argument to `tracemalloc.start()`, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.start).

However, in my minimal test setup (code below) I start tracemalloc with argument 25, but I only get 1 frame in the backtrace, where I would expect 2:

### What I got as output

```
me@my_machine:/tmp$ python ./test_tm.py 

Entry: /tmp/test_tm_utils.py:2: size=3533 KiB (+3533 KiB), count=99746 (+99746), average=36 B
Traceback:
  /tmp/test_tm_utils.py:2
```

### What I expected as output

I would expect *two* lines, like so:

```
Entry: /tmp/test_tm_utils.py:2: size=3533 KiB (+3533 KiB), count=99746 (+99746), average=36 B
Traceback:
  /tmp/test_tm_utils.py:2
  /tmp/test_tm.py:10
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### Minimal code sample

Main program in _/tmp/test_tm.py_:

```
import tracemalloc

tracemalloc.start(25)
import test_tm_utils


if __name__ == '__main__':

    s1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    test_tm_utils.myfun()

    s2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()

    diff = s2.compare_to(s1, 'lineno')

    for entry in diff[:1]:
        print('\nEntry: {}'.format(entry))
        print('Traceback:')
        for line in entry.traceback:
            print('  {}'.format(line))
```

And the memory leak function in `test_tm_utils.py`:

```
def myfun(lst=list()):
    lst.append([i for i in range(100000)])
```

Answer (score 5):

The secret is the key_type parameter. You must use the value `"traceback"` to get all the lines specified in `tracemalloc.start()`. If you use `"lineno"` or `"filename"` you only get one line.

This is true for both [Statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.Snapshot.statistics) or in your case [compare_to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.Snapshot.compare_to).

So your code should look something like this:

```
s2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()

diff = s2.compare_to(s1, 'traceback') # This is the only change

for entry in diff[:1]:
    print('\nEntry: {}'.format(entry))
    print('Traceback:')
    for line in entry.traceback:
        print('  {}'.format(line))
```