# Python tracemalloc's "compare_to" function delivers always "StatisticDiff" objects with len(traceback)=1

Tags: python, compare, diff, snapshot, tracemalloc

Using Python's 3.5 tracemalloc module as follows

```
tracemalloc.start(25)  # (I also tried PYTHONTRACEMALLOC=25)
snapshot_start = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
...  # my code is running
snapshot_stop = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
diff = snapshot_stop.compare_to(snapshot_start, 'lineno')
tracemalloc.stop()
```

leads in a list of StatisticDiff instances where each instance has a traceback with only 1 (the most recent) frame.

Any hints how to get there the full stack trace for each StatisticDiff instance?

Thank you!
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `'traceback'` instead of `'lineno'` when calling `compare_to()` to get more than one line.

BTW, I also answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935252/how-to-get-more-frames-from-backtrace-in-tracemalloc-snapshot-comparisons-pytho) with a little more detail.